# Updating a File in C

Tags: c, multithreading, file, rename

So, i'm trying to do in a while operation inside a thread
1st-
Open a file A that can or cannot exist
2nd
Merge  A with  a buffer in a temporary file  B
3rd-
delete A , and rename the temporary File B to A
The problem is, it seems i'm renaming the files o unlink in the wrong way/order and i can't find how to do it right.
I update the content in the variable endofordering in a diferent thread, which seems to work fine.

```
void *fusiona (void *x) { 
    int i,iniciat = 0;
    short s;
    t_sems * sems = (t_sems*)x;
    FILE * f2;
    FILE * f3;


    while(!endofordering){
        i=0;
        sem_wait (&sems->semFusionador);

        pthread_mutex_lock (&mut);
        if ((f2 = fopen("numord", "ab+")) == NULL){
            perror("Abriendo mal"); 
        }
        if ((f3 = fopen("numtmp", "wb")) == NULL){
            perror("Abriendo mal"); 
        }
        if(!iniciat){

            fwrite(bufo,sizeof(short),10,f2);
            iniciat = 1;    
        }else{
            fseek(f2,SEEK_SET,0);
            fread(&s,sizeof(short), 1, f2);

             while(!feof(f2)&&i < BUFFERLENGHT){

                if(s < bufo[i]){
                    fwrite(&s,sizeof(short),1,f3);
                    fread(&s,sizeof(short), 1, f2);
                    printf("escribo la i = %i y leo s = %u\n",i,s); 
                }else if( s> bufo[i]){
                    fwrite(&bufo[i],sizeof(short),1,f3);
                    i++;

                }else{
                    fwrite(&bufo[i],sizeof(short),1,f3);    
                    fwrite(&s,sizeof(short),1,f3);
                    i++;
                    fread(&s,sizeof(short), 1, f2);

                }
            }

            if(feof(f2)){

                for(;i<BUFFERLENGHT;i++){
                    fwrite(&bufo[i],sizeof(short),1,f3);

                }           
            }

            //WRONG ORDER??

            fclose(f2);
            fclose(f3);
            unlink("numord");
            rename("numtmp","numord");

        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mut);
        printf("gbye mutex\n");


    }

return (NULL);
```

The idea (which may be helpful) is to update  merging file f2(numord) with a buffer for as long as i recieve post to my semaphore and, in the end have a sorted file f2. 
The problem is, for some unkonwn reason my program deletes both  files in every iteration of the while instead of of removing the old file (f2/numord) and renaming the temporary file (f3/numtmp) with the name of the old file.That is not the intended behaviour.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? You have told us what you have attempted to do but you have not clearly described the current behaviour of your program.

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully this time i made myself clear!

Comment: Is `BUFFERLENGHT` correct? You have `LENGTH` misspelled

Comment: Check for errors from `unlink()` and `rename()`.

Comment: Yup, the  value is correct. Just a little mistake from a non-native speaker!

Comment: You are truncating `f3` and doing it over and over in an infinite loop. When will it end?

Comment: I edited to code to make it simplier to understand, but it seems, i'm making people confused with it, i'll edit the code to show how i get a  boolean global variable.

Comment: Posting code snippets is inherently unclear. Please post an [mcve]. That's the only guaranteed way to avoid confusion.

Comment: You'll be surprised, the value of `endofordering` may not happen at the exact time you think it does.

Comment: After one thread changes the value of `endofordering`, it is not guaranteed that the other thread will see the new value immediately. This is unsafe. You could end up looping more than necessary and ending up with a truncated file.